# java PreparedStatement Arraylist SQL

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, arraylist

Can not insert new values to my DB from ArrayList; i want to add all ArrayList to DB columns **list, title, about** values from ArrayLists pars.getListId(), getTitleId(), pars.getAboutAr().

```
String query = "insert into test (list, title, about)" + "VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

    try {
        pars.htmlParse("hello");
        PreparedStatement preparedStmt = db.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);
        for (int i = 0; i < pars.getListId().size(); i++) {
            preparedStmt.setString(1, pars.getListId().get(i));
            preparedStmt.executeUpdate();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < pars.getTitleId().size(); i++) {
            preparedStmt.setString(2, pars.getTitleId().get(i));
            preparedStmt.executeUpdate();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < pars.getAboutAr().size(); i++) {
            preparedStmt.setString(3, pars.getAboutAr().get(i));
            preparedStmt.executeUpdate();
        }
        preparedStmt.execute();


        } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace you get.

Comment: So your `pars` has three separate lists? not just one array list? The problem is that you have to set all columns of the same row before you `executeUpdate` it, but if you have three separate lists, you may have a problem if they are not of the same length.

Comment: it has 3 ArrayList;s. Now i understand, that they have different lengths. But it does not solve my problem.

Comment: do you have some error?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 2
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.fillSendPacket(PreparedStatement.java:2176)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1993)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1937)

Comment: For each element in the list, you need to execute a single insert statement. Now, when you get that working, you can explore using a batch update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set all three columns before you call `executeUpdate` even once.

You are doing:

```
        preparedStmt.setString(1, pars.getListId().get(i));
        preparedStmt.executeUpdate();
```

So you only set the first parameter in the prepared statement, and then you call `executeUpdate`. But you need to have all three.

You should have a loop that inserts all three together:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < pars.getListId().size(); i++) {
        preparedStmt.setString(1, pars.getListId().get(i));
        preparedStmt.setString(2, pars.getTitleId().get(i));
        preparedStmt.setString(3, pars.getAboutAr().get(i));
        preparedStmt.executeUpdate();
    }
```

This sets all three columns in the statement before executing it. So you will get a proper insert statement with all values set.

One problem here is that it might happen that `pars.getListId()` has 5 items, for example, while `pars.getTitleId()` and `pars.getAboutAr()` have 4 items. Then, when you run the loop above, when `i` gets to the value `4` you'll get an exception, because `pars.getTitleId()` doesn't have a value 4 (because it has only 4 items).

This can have several solutions.

1. If you know that the result of your parsing is always equal-length lists, then it's not a problem.
2. You can insert only the values up to the shortest list. You can have a calculation like this:

   ```
   int minSize = Collections.min( Arrays.asList( pars.getListId().size(),
                                                 pars.getTitleId().size(),
                                                 pars.getAboutAr().size() ) );
   ```

   And then use

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < minSize; i++) {
       preparedStmt.setString(1, pars.getListId().get(i));
       preparedStmt.setString(2, pars.getTitleId().get(i));
       preparedStmt.setString(3, pars.getAboutAr().get(i));
       preparedStmt.executeUpdate();
   }
   ```

   And then it will give you as many rows as the shortest list.
3. You can go with the longest list (do `max` instead of `min` in the calculation above) and set nulls for the missing values (that is, check if the list is shorter than `i` requires. If so, use `setNull` instead of `setString`.
4. Personally, I would not build `pars` the way you have, with three separate lists. Instead, I would create a class, perhaps named `Par` or whatever makes sense, which has `id`, `title` and `about` fields. Then I would create a single list of `Par` objects in my `pars` instead of three separate lists. And then you will not have a problem with different lengths, and the data structure will be more like what you have in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your code to each have a param 1, 2 and 3 before you executeUpdate().

**I assume your lists have equal amount of entries (will break otherwise)**

```
    for (int i = 0; i < pars.getListId().size(); i++) {
        preparedStmt.setString(1, pars.getListId().get(i));
        preparedStmt.setString(2, pars.getTitleId().get(i));
        preparedStmt.setString(3, pars.getAboutAr().get(i));
        preparedStmt.executeUpdate();
    }
```

Now you have all 3 set per insert.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to set each parameter and then executing the update, which leaves the query in an invalidate state (as not all the parameters are set), you should, for each element, set each parameter and then execute the update.

A better solution would be then to use a batch update process, for example

```
String query = "insert into test (list, title, about)" + "VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
try (PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query)) {
    pars.htmlParse("hello");
    for (int index = 0; index < pars.getListId().size(); index++) {
        ps.setString(1, pars.getListId().get(index));
        ps.setString(2, pars.getTitleId().get(index));
        ps.setString(3, pars.getAboutAr().get(index));
        ps.addBatch();
    }
    ps.executeBatch();
} catch (SQLException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```